# Regex Issue JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to take a string and check whether or not it contains a lowercase letter or number, and then if so push that letter or number to an array.

```
for(let i = 0; i < datearg.length; i++) 
    {
        log.info(datearg.charAt(i));
        if(/[a-z]/.test(datearg.charAt(i))) letter_num++; letters.push(datearg.charAt(i));
        if(/[0-9]/.test(datearg.charAt(i))) number_num++; numbers.push(datearg.charAt(i));
    }
```

However, both if statements always evaluate to true and the arrays end up containing every single character in datearg. Anyone know why?

Comment: you need a block of code ... `{ code1; code2; code3;}` ... line breaks mean very little to javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
if(/[a-z]/.test(datearg.charAt(i))) letter_num++; letters.push(datearg.charAt(i));
```

is equivalent to

```
if(/[a-z]/.test(datearg.charAt(i))) { letter_num++; }
letters.push(datearg.charAt(i));
```

i.e. `push` is not conditional. This is the primary reason why many style guides heavily discourage control structures without braces (which only take a single statement).

Comment: Ah, yes. I don't know how this one slipped past me. Thanks.